# Pseudcode to java

Tags: java, pseudocode, code-conversion, bresenham

I have looked around for the past hour or so but I can not find any help on this problem. I am trying to convert this pseudocode to java and can not figure out what I am doing wrong(it ever prints anything).

```
function line(x0, x1, y0, y1)
     boolean steep := abs(y1 - y0) > abs(x1 - x0)
     if steep then
         swap(x0, y0)
         swap(x1, y1)
     if x0 > x1 then
         swap(x0, x1)
         swap(y0, y1)
     int deltax := x1 - x0
     int deltay := abs(y1 - y0)
     real error := 0
     real deltaerr := deltay / deltax
     int ystep
     int y := y0
     if y0 < y1 then ystep := 1 else ystep := -1
     for x from x0 to x1
         if steep then plot(y,x) else plot(x,y)
         error := error + deltaerr
         if error ≥ 0.5 then
             y := y + ystep
             error := error - 1.0
```

My conversion is:

```
public static void line(int x0,int x1,int y0,int y1) {
     boolean steep = Math.abs(y1 - y0) > Math.abs(x1 - x0);
     if(steep) {
         swap(x0, y0);
         swap(x1, y1);
     }
     if (x0 > x1) {
         swap(x0, x1);
         swap(y0, y1);
     }
     int deltax = x1 - x0;
     int deltay = Math.abs(y1 - y0);
     float error = 0;
     float deltaerr = deltay / (float)deltax;
     int ystep;
     int y = y0;

     if(y0 < y1) ystep = 1;
     else ystep = -1;

     //for x from x0 to x1
     for(int x = x0; x < x1;x++)
         if (steep) plot(y,x);
         else plot(x,y);
         error = error + deltaerr;
         if (error >= 0.5f) {
             y = y + ystep;
             error = error - 1.0f;
         }
    }

//method plot
    private static void plot(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println(x+":"+y);
    }
//method swap
    private static void swap(int x0, int x1) {
        int copy = x0;           
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = copy;
    }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please make your question self-standing by pasting in the code here.  If the code is too large for that, then make it small enough to demonstrate just what you need help with.

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful, but this is mostly implemented in zxing: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/Detector.java (near line 300)

Comment: Don't follow the pseudocode word for word. The implementation is different for every language, not to mention that it's always better to write your own code.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a `swap()` method like that with `int`s. Since they are *primitives*, they are *passed by value*, and changing the local variables inside the method will have no effect on the variables you use as arguments.
Do the swapping directly in the `line()` method instead.

A second thing is that your `for` loop looks wrong. Based on your indentation, you probably want to use curly braces around that entire block.